# Click Once Deployment Requires Visual Studio Installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I try to deploy a Click Once Installer but run into a very strange issue: 
The installer runs fine but as soon as the application is supposed to start it crashes with the following message

> [MyApp] has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for
>   the inconvenience.

and no useful information about the cause. As soon as I install Visual Studio Professional 2012 on the same machine, the application starts fine but sometimes behaves very strange (e.g. I have to click to red close button twice to close the application). Funny enough, the problem not always appears, I suspect it has something to do with the order in which I install the .Net Framework/Visual Studio/the Click Once installer.

I am pretty much lost here .....

Btw: The framework targetVersion and supportedRuntime of the Click-Once installer are 4.0 and 4.0.30319 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) handler to your app. This will allow you to see the exception that is causing the crash.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
    MessageBox.Show("Unhandled domain exception:\n\n" + ex.Message);
}
```

Note that the use of `MessageBox` is only for debugging. A logging system should be used for your release version.